# How do I extend a parameterized abstract class with a more specific generic type?

Tags: java, generics, apache-camel

I'm new to generics. I have an abstract class (1) with an abstract method. I have another abstract class (2) with a few abstract methods that I want shared in some DTOs (3,4). I want a concrete extension of (1) to work on anything that extends (2).

1.

```
//I want R to be anything here
public abstract class AggregatedEmailerRoute<R> extends RouteBuilder {

    public static String EMAILER_ROUTE = "direct:aggregated-emailer-route";
    
@Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
        from(EMAILER_ROUTE)
                .bean(this, "convertToEmailBody(${body},${headers})")
                .to("mock:wherever");
    }

    protected abstract String convertToEmailBody(List<R> body, Map<String,Object> headers);
```

2. 

```
public abstract class StagingError { //or should this be an interface?
    public abstract Integer getId();
    public abstract String getErrorNote();
    public abstract LocalDateTime getErrorDate();
}
```

Two classes that extend StagingError:
3.

```
public class Bill extends StagingError {

    private Integer id;
    private String errorNote;
    private LocalDateTime getErrorDate;
    //other fields, getters/setters
```

4. 

```
public class Payment extends StagingError {

    private Integer id;
    private String errorNote;
    private LocalDateTime getErrorDate;
    //other fields, getters/setters
```

5. 

```
public class StagingEmailErrorRoute extends AggregatedEmailerRoute<R extends StagingError> {

    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
        super.configure();

        from(jpa(Bill.class.getName())
                .query("some query")
        )
                .to(EMAILER_ROUTE);

        from(jpa(Payment.class.getName())
                .query("some other query")
        )
                .to(EMAILER_ROUTE);

    }


@Override //But here I want to work on anything that implements StagingError so this method can work on Payment OR Bill 
    protected String convertToEmailBody(List<T extends StagingError> body, Map<String,Object> headers) {
        return 
                body
                .stream()
                .map(e -> "Staging entity ID: " + e.getId() +
                            "\n\tError: " + e.getErrorNote() +
                            "\n\tWhen: " + format("%tc",e.getErrorDate().atZone(EST.get())) +
                            "\n")
                .collect(joining("\n"));
```

Comment: you can use java "wildcard" for that purpose.

Comment: @MohammadRezaKhahani Could you explain a bit more, perhaps with an example given the sample code above?

Answer (score 1):

Understanding the concept of [variance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_(computer_science)) is the key to answering your question.

The definitions you provided are almost correct, though still both `StagingEmailErrorRoute` and `AggregatedEmailerRoute` classes need to be slightly modified to fit your expectations.

In particular, the `convertToEmailBody(List<R> body, Map<String,Object> headers)` as it should meet at least these criteria:

1. It has to accept a list of `R` or or a list of its subclasses.
2. Inside the method you need have access to the elements of `body` as instances `R` (another words you need [a producer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31634364/1689608) of `R`).

This is achieved by declaring the body as `List<? extends R>`:

```
convertToEmailBody(List<? extends R> body, Map<String, Object> headers)
```

Then your specific subclass `StagingEmailErrorRoute extends AggregatedEmailerRoute<StagingError>` is allowed to accept either `StagingError` or its descendants and work with them as instances of `R` (inside the stream):

```
public class StagingEmailErrorRoute extends AggregatedEmailerRoute<StagingError> {

    @Override
    protected String convertToEmailBody(List<? extends StagingError> body, Map<String, Object> headers) {
        return body
            .stream()
            .map(e -> "Staging entity ID: " + e.getId() +
                "\n\tError: " + e.getErrorNote() +
                "\n\tWhen: " + format("%tc",e.getErrorDate().atZone(EST.get())) +
                "\n")
            .collect(joining("\n"));
    }
}
```

---

**EDIT: Example usage of `StagingEmailErrorRoute`**:

```
StagingEmailErrorRoute route = new StagingEmailErrorRoute();

//1. consume a list as a mix of `StagingError` descendants
List<StagingError> stagingErrors = new ArrayList<>();
stagingErrors.add(new Bill());
stagingErrors.add(new Payment());

route.convertToEmailBody(stagingErrors, headers);

//2. consume a list of specific subclasses of `StagingError` (i.e. Bill)
List<Bill> billErrors = new ArrayList<>();
billErrors.add(new Bill());

route.convertToEmailBody(billErrors, headers);
```

Comment: How could you pass value to body parameter? I tried some ways but I couldn't find an acceptable type for body which also acceptable for List<>.add() method. May you add some code for that?

Comment: @MohammadRezaKhahani sure, updated my answer

Comment: Now I get it; I have to use the raw generic. It's the correct answer, and I give a vote up. Thank you @dshelya

Answer (score 0):

You can write AggregatedEmailerRoute class something like this:

```
public abstract class AggregatedEmailerRoute<R> extends RouteBuilder {
    //...
    protected abstract String convertToEmailBody(List<R> body, Map<String, Object> headers);
}
```

And for StagingEmailErrorRoute:

```
public class StagingEmailErrorRoute<T extends StagingError> extends AggregatedEmailerRoute<T> {

    @Override
    protected String convertToEmailBody(List<T> body, Map<String, Object> headers) {
        return null; 
    }
}
```

then you can pass any class that extends StaginError, in your case Payment and Bill:

[image: sample code]

I hope that is helpful.

Comment: The OP specified that, quote: "//I want R to be anything here public abstract class AggregatedEmailerRoute<R>" , so you cannot put `StagingError` a bound there

Comment: @dshelya You're right, and I updated the AggregatedEmailerRoute.

Comment: The updated solution is still a bit unpractical. First, the class `StagingEmailErrorRoute` is now generic, so you must specify a type
whenever you instantiate it: `StagingEmailErrorRoute<XXX> route;`, moreover the type argument cannot be anything besides `StagingError` if you want a single `route` instance to be able to consume subclasses of StagingError. Also, because the `body` is declared as `List<T>` - you have to use an invariant list (which cannot be anything else but `List<StagingError>`)

Comment: Of course, if keeping multiple instances like `StagingEmailErrorRoute<Bill> billRoute`, `StagingEmailErrorRoute<Payment> paymentRoute` per each subclass is not a problem - the proposed solution would work.